# how to form a cross pattern of one between zeros using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

i want a good method to insert the one inside zeros in a cross pattern with ones on top rows and bottom rows.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=int)
a[0,:] = 1 
a[-1,:] = 1 

for i in range(1,n):
    a[i,-i-1] = 1

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1]  
[0 1 0]  
[1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.eye` and reverse the rows, then assign with slices:

```
a = np.eye(n, dtype=int)[::-1]
a[[0,-1]] = 1
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```